# What is the best way to filter bad HTML Content from Posts using AntiXSS Library?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, xss

I want to create an Asp.net Website and I want to prevent Cross Site Scripting. I have a page with Summernote (a WYSIWYG HTML Editor), which, when submittet, posts HTML Code to MVC ActionResult via form or Ajax Post.
This Method saves this Code in my Database as content/body of a message. On another Site, you can display the content, which shows formating things like Lists etc.

Because of security reasons i want to filter the content i recieve from client. I am using the AntiXSS Library from Microsoft.

A part of my MVC Code:

```
[ValidateInput(false), HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateMessage(string subject, string body)
{
    var cleanBody = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(body);
    //do the Database thing here
}
```

The major problem is, that it kills my HTML Elements with  tag, because it removes the src=""

should be:

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,some/ultra/long/picture/code/here" data-filename="grafik.png"></p>
```

remaining:

```
<p><img src="" alt=""><img src=""></p>
```

What can i do to prevent this?
Is there a way to add an exception rule?
Is there an another better way?
How does it work?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing anymore as the "AntiXSS Library". It used to be a separate library, but Microsoft moved it into .Net, so it's now under [System.Web.Security.AntiXss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss?view=netframework-4.8).

The reason this is important is that you need a **sanitizer**. The way you are using AntiXss currently will take a list of html tags and a list of attributes to those tags, and will remove everything else from your html code. That's not very good for you, because you only want to remove javascript, regardless of tags or attributes. Let's take for example `<a>`, with its `href` attribute. You most probably want to allow your users to insert links, but you don't want them to be able to insert javascript via `<a href="javascript: ...">`. So you cannot filter out `href` for `<a>`, but if you leave it, your page will be vulnerable to XSS.

So you want a sanitizer that only removes javascript. In the original AntiXSS library there *was* a sanitizer, but when Microsoft moved it to .Net, the sanitizer was left out.

So in short, AntiXss will not help you with your current usecase.

You can find proper html sanitizers like for example Google Caja (client-side sanitizer [here](https://github.com/google/caja/blob/master/src/com/google/caja/plugin/html-sanitizer.js)), or many others. The point is, even if this sanitizer is in javascript (on the client), if you carefully don't insert your data into the page DOM before sanitizing it, it will all be fine.

So in short, you could just save any data from the HTML editor to your database as is without any transformation (mind sql injection of course, but current data access technologies should have that covered), and then when such data is displayed, send it to the client without adding it to the page dom (like as json data for example, but properly encoded for json then of course!), then run your sanitizer that will remove any javascript, and then add it to the page.

The reason this is very good is because your wysiwyg html editor will likely have a preview screen. Don't forget to add sanitization to previews as well, otherwise the preview will be vulnerable to XSS. If sanitization was on the server, you would have to send the editor contents to the server, sanitize it and send it back to your user for preview - not very user-friendly.

Also note that many wysiwyg editors support hooking into their rendering and adding such a sanitizer. If an editor does not support this and does not have its own sanitizer, that cannot be made secure with regard to XSS.

Comment: Thank you verry much, I gave it a try and it worked how I wanted